# What's the logic of inherited constructor order parameters

Tags: magento2, module, orders, parameter, construct

I have this module class

```
namespace VendorName\Module\Block\Magento\Framework\Pricing;

use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\AmountInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Layout;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use VendorName\Module\Helper\Data;

/**
* Class Render
* @package VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Magento\Framework\Pricing
*/
class Render extends \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render
{

/**
 * @var \Cart2Quote\Not2Order\Helper\Data
 */
private $dataHelper;

public function __construct(Data $dataHelper, Template\Context $context, Layout $priceLayout, array $data)
{
    $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    parent::__construct($context, $priceLayout, $data);
}


}
```

So i got this error

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to VendorName\Module\Block\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::__construct() must be of the type array, null given
```

The correct constructor is

```
public function __construct(Template\Context $context, Layout $priceLayout,array $data = [], Data $dataHelper)
{
    $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    parent::__construct($context, $priceLayout, $data);
}
```

But i don't know why it's correct, which is the logic for the constructor parameters order

This is the main class '\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render.php' constructor

```
 public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    Layout $priceLayout,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->priceLayout = $priceLayout;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed out `= []` after `array $data`, if the parameter is not provided to the constructer it will then be null, as you haven't specified a default of `[]`

Comment: How can know the parameters order or it's not important?

Comment: I think we should follow parent constuctor parameters order

Comment: You'll need to provide parameters to `parent::__construct()` in the same order they're defined in that parent constructor and, while it's not essential, it's generally good practise to use the same order for your constructor